# How can I debug loops more efficiently on Eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse

I am trying to thoroughly understand the code I found on [Github](https://github.com/claf/MJPEG/blob/master/tima_seq_version/src/main.c). I am running this code on Eclipse (Version: 3.6.1
Build id: M20100909-0800).

I want to efficiently debug these lines of code:

```
        for (index_X = 0; index_X < nb_MCU_X; index_X++) {
          for (index_Y = 0; index_Y < nb_MCU_Y; index_Y++) {
            for (index = 0; index < SOS_section.n; index++) {
              uint32_t component_index = component_order[index];
              int nb_MCU = ((SOF_component[component_index].HV >> 4) & 0xf) * (SOF_component[component_index].HV & 0x0f);
              for (chroma_ss = 0; chroma_ss < nb_MCU; chroma_ss++) {
                unpack_block(movie, & scan_desc, index, MCU);
                iqzz_block(MCU, unZZ_MCU, DQT_table[SOF_component[component_index].q_table]);
                IDCT(unZZ_MCU, YCbCr_MCU_ds[component_index] + (64 * chroma_ss));
              }

              upsampler(YCbCr_MCU_ds[component_index], YCbCr_MCU[component_index],
                max_ss_h / ((SOF_component[component_index].HV >> 4) & 0xf), max_ss_v / ((SOF_component[component_index].HV) & 0xf), max_ss_h, max_ss_v);
            }

            if (color && (SOF_section.n > 1)) {
              YCbCr_to_ARGB(YCbCr_MCU, RGB_MCU, max_ss_h, max_ss_v);
            } else {
              to_NB(YCbCr_MCU, RGB_MCU, max_ss_h, max_ss_v);
            }

            screen_cpyrect(index_Y * MCU_sy * max_ss_h, index_X * MCU_sx * max_ss_v, MCU_sy * max_ss_h, MCU_sx * max_ss_v, RGB_MCU);
          }
        }
```

The code above contains a number of loops and stepping over every line of code many times is laborious (`nb_MCU_X` is 18 and `nb_MCU_Y` is 32).

I tried to change the values of `index_X` and `index_Y` in Debug mode. I thought doing so would take me to a point in the program where more of the code will have been processed. However, Only `index_X` and `index_Y` changed to the values I gave them but all other dependent values did not change with them. Consequently, the behavior of the program was distorted and it began behaving erratically.

I tried setting breakpoints immediately after this section of code. However, it does not allow me to see the next step that occurs after the section of the code above is processed. I want to know instantly what the condition of the code will be when `index_X` or `index_Y` is at any value of my choosing.

Is there a way for me in Eclipse to go ***forward in time*** and have more iterations processed instead of stepping over each line of the code?

What should I do if, for example, `index_Y` is currently 0 but I want to go instantly to a point in the program where `index_Y` is 7 and the rest of the code has also changed accordingly?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Eclipse's C debugger, but you should be able to set conditional breakpoints that only stop when specified conditions are true (index_X and index_Y have the values you want), or hitcount breakpoints that will only stop after the code has run over them a given number of times.

Comment: Right click on breakpoint and set the confitions

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216593/breakpoint-in-loop-after-large-number-of-iterations-in-eclipse?rq=1) answer to also be quite useful.